# jquery validation for an input text to accept only either a number or word or date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Can any one help me to validate an input text box that should allow only word or number or date, no other special characters allowed. And even combination of special characters or word or number shouldn't allowed. And there will be a drop down box before the text box and if the 2nd or 3rd option selected in dropdown box then only it should done as i said, in the else case its no need.

```
<table class="standard upload-file" width='98%' id="filterRowtable">
    <td>
        <form:input path="badRows[${status.index}].value" />
    </td>
</table>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What does your date format look like?

Comment: mm-dd-yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy they both

Comment: Does the drop down decide what neds to be restricted like date/numeric/words?

Comment: no it doesn't decide the kind of input for text box its just says whether word or number or date allowed or not but not specifically like only number or only date..

Comment: if u selected 2nd or 3rd option in the drop down box then the text box should allow only number or date or word,that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function like this to examine the text entered:

```
function (filterText) {
        if (filterText === "") {
            return true;
        }
        if (filterText._array.length === 0) {
            return true;
        }
        var iChars = "~!#$^&%*+=\\\;{}|\":<>?",
        txt = filterText._array[0].FieldValue,
        i;
        for (i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
            if (iChars.indexOf(txt.charAt(i)) !== -1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
```